# Issue with GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have been using Cloud SQL with our django project since last 4 months. We have used master-slave approach. Created One master instance and one replica. But since last 3 days replicas are seem to be giving connectivity timeout issues and we lost a lot of data.

Anybody could advise on that matter, please?

Comment: Not an expert (or even very advanced at all) here, but could you just write to the master one, and just use the replica for reads? I don't believe this is really a question for SO though.

Comment: Master is fully operational. Replicas are for read-only operations and it's not accessive. It happens that it start working but then stopped again.

Comment: Debugging problems is both an art and a science. Your question has no details whereby we can help you. Network connection timeout issues can be caused by a large number of items. Google search for guides that can help you understand network connectivity so that you understand how to troubleshoot. You must figure out what is failing - then post a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

The only information I was able to find in the docs about the [connection timeout](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#timeout) is the following:

> There are many reasons why a connection attempt might not succeed.
> Network communication is never guaranteed, and the database might be
> temporarily unable to respond. Make sure your application handles
> broken or unsuccessful connections gracefully.

If it was working without issues for the last 4 months and suddenly started throwing the connectivity timeout, I think the best would be to create a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) or reach out to the [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support).